# How do I retrieve data from a child object in a base object array?

Tags: c#, arraylist

Say I have a GameObject array with child objects inside of it:

```
GameObjects = new List<GameObject>
        {
            new Tile(0, 0, new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 0 }),
            new BuyTile(1, 0),
            new BuyTile(0, 1),
            new BuyTile(-1, 0),
            new BuyTile(0, -1)
        };
```

And I want to access a property in a Tile object in this array.

```
public void UpdateResources()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < GameObjects.Count; i++)
        {
            if (GameObjects[i] is Tile)
            {
                /* I want to read a property of the Tile here, and it's not in the abstract class 
                 * GameObject.
                */
            }
        }
    }
```

How do I do so?
I couldn't find anything myself about this issue, but if someone has a link to another related question I will gladly accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```cs
public void UpdateResources()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < GameObjects.Count; i++)
        {
            if (GameObjects[i] is Tile t)
            {
                 t.X // <- read property
                
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`as`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/type-testing-and-cast#as-operator) operator and null check:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < GameObjects.Count; i++)
    {
        var tile = GameObjects[i] as Tile;
        if (tile != null)
        {
            // use tile 
        }
    }
```

If your version of unity supports C# 7.0 you can use [`is` operator with the type pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/type-testing-and-cast#type-testing-with-pattern-matching):

```
    for (int i = 0; i < GameObjects.Count; i++)
    {
        if (GameObjects[i] is Tile tile)
        {
            // use tile
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try *Linq*:

```
public void UpdateResources() {
  foreach (Tile tile in GameObjects.OfType<Tile>()) {
    //TODO: put relevant code here, e.g.
    // tile.SomeProperty = tile.SomeProperty - 5; 
  }
}
```